# Is there some default sorting by Xodus getAll()?

Tags: xodus

Is there some default sorting, when using getAll() method by Xodus Entity Stores?

`EntityIterable entities = txn.getAll("User");`

It seems that, it's sorted by EntityId so by creation order...can one rely on it?

Answer (score 0):

You're right, entities returned by `getAll()` are sorted by entity id. Even though this behavior is not documented, it's extremely unlikely that it will change somewhen. So yes, you can rely on it.